# Make recompiling even if files unchanged

Tags: linux, makefile

I had compiled linux kernel code earlier while it was in /usr/src/. It took 2 hrs to cmplt make. Today I just moved that source code folder from /usr/src/ to my home directory.

When I gave make command again it started generating .o files even though I didnt change a single file. Plz help me because I dont want to spend two more hours doin make.

I think this behavior of make is because it uses modification times of the files...I have also tried putting back the source code files in /usr/src/ (where it was earlier) , but that too didnt work. Thanks :)

Comment: are /usr/src and /home (or wherever your home dir is) on different file systems? you can't "move" across filesystem, so it'll actually be a copy+delete operation. that'd mean new inodes, possibly different timestamps, etc...

Comment: no ..i just did a normal ubuntu installation in virtualbox

Comment: @MarcB how can /usr/src and /home be on different file systems because both require ext* , do u mean different partitions ?

Comment: file system can refer to both the physical drive partition, and the "organizing system" used (e.g. fat, ext, ntfs, etc...). I'm talking about partitions.

Comment: @MarcB isnt this a common issue with make ? or am doin something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just copied the sources but not the already compiled files? Also never compile something outside of your home directory. At least not if you had to be root for this.

Comment: hey i did this " mv /usr/src/linux-3.7.6 /home/jignesh

Comment: and i think it had moved all the files

Comment: What about ownership changes? I mean files where owned by root and now? If the compiled files are still owned by root it is likely make recompiles everything. Two hours waiting  for the linux kernel to compile is not that much ;)

Comment: hey bt i can do sudo make...and that still doesnt work...two hrs is not a big time i know...bt still it doesnt sound cool that i had to make again for such a silly mistake